# Connection to get data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

In my project I have to integrate the library and parse the files presented in csv format. To access the library and get the information form that file I use $ajax as follows:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://stats.xxx.tv/osexternal/reports/xxxxx/xxx_2014_YTD/2014-03-12.csv",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',  
      username: 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
      password: 'dT$xxxx%949',
      success: function (){
          console.log('success');
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
     });
  });
<script>
```

Can anyone let me know what's the wrong with this approach as I am getting cross domain problem.And please let me know any alternatives by using gems.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please move it from On hold

Comment: see this link it may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681470/access-to-restricted-uri-denied-code-1012-cross-domain-ajax-request

Comment: @Gowri Yes I saw that one, but the actual problem is not with cross domain because I can get details when we open the url in browser.

Comment: Why still in on hold ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're running into appears to be a CORs issue of some kind. Things to note about CORs issues:

- It is a security policy for Javascript, so it only affects calls in/from JS.
- Being able to access it from the browser 'directly' doesn't have anything to do with CORs
- CORS can be really irritating

Now, on how to solve it, you can try adding:

`with_credentials: true` to the Ajax arguments, but I have a feeling it's going to be something weirder than that... as well, since you have to include a *username* and *password* it's probably best not to expose those on the client for anyone to have...

So, what I'd do is make the call on the server (example is for a rails controller action, but the method could be used in a Sinatra app just the same) then return the CSV to the browser:

```
require 'net/http'
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  def get_csv
    uri = URI('http://stats.adap.tv/osexternal/reports/xxxxx/xxx_2014_YTD/2014-03-12.csv')
    csv_request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    csv_request.basic_auth("username", "password")
    csv_data = csv_request.request.body
    csv
  end
end
```

I'm assuming you are using Ruby because of your "gems" reference. Here's *the* doc for Net::HTTP

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

and a slightly easier to digest version:

http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

In general, it'll always be easier (and safer) to have your server make a request to an external host (this is a broad generalization and there are absolutely cases where this isn't what you want). If you need to make a cross domain request I'd suggest starting with:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

It'll probably give you some good tips to figure out why it's not currently working.

Best,