# Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to ping a server after an interval using jquery. I found jquery ajax function on internet working for so many people but it throws exception
"Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012"" in Firefox, Errorcode 0 in IE and 404 Chrome for www.google.com. I don't understand what is the problem. Following is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Server availability</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        var req = function () {
            count = count + 1;
            var link = $('#testURL').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: testURL,
                success: function () {
                    $('#spnStatus').html($('#spnStatus').html() + '<br/><br/>' + link + ' Checked ' + count + ' times. Server available');
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    //alert(xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);

                    $('#spnStatus').html($('#spnStatus').html() + '<br/><br/>' + link + ' Checked ' + count
                    + ' times. Server not available. Error Code:' + xhr.status + "<br/> Exception:" + thrownError);
                }
            });
            //Call it again.
            setTimeout(function () {
                req();
            }, 5000);
        };
        var count = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            req();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="testURL" type="text" value="http://www.google.com" /><br />
    <span id="spnStatus">Not checked yet.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to restricted URI denied code: 1012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283/access-to-restricted-uri-denied-code-1012)

Comment: yes it is but its not working that way :S

Comment: You cannot access pages from other domains with AJAX unless they are of JSONP type. So if you cannot put a JSONP page on the *other* domain (*because you might not control it*) you can only use a server side proxy (*local*) to check the other page, and you AJAX to that local proxy .. read http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html for more on that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaby aka G. Petrioli Thanks you'r second comment is the answer for me. :)